# Mapbox is unable to show device location

Tags: android, mapbox, android-location, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I have a Fragment with Mapbox and I want to display the device location on it.

```
class SampleMapFragment : Fragment(), PermissionsListener {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentExploreBinding

    @Inject
    lateinit var permissionsManager: PermissionsManager

    private lateinit var mapboxMap: MapboxMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Mapbox.getInstance(requireContext().applicationContext, getString(R.string.mapbox_token))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (!::binding.isInitialized) {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_explore,
                container,
                false
            )

            binding.lifecycleOwner = this

            binding.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setUpMap()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setUpMap() {
        binding.mapView.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
            this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) { loadedMapStyle ->
                starLocationTracking(loadedMapStyle)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun starLocationTracking(loadedMapStyle: Style) {
        if (!PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(requireContext())) {
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(requireActivity())
            return
        }

        initLocationComponent(loadedMapStyle)
    }

    private fun initLocationComponent(loadedMapStyle: Style) {

        val customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(requireActivity())
            .elevation(5f)
            .accuracyAlpha(.6f)
            .accuracyColor(Color.RED)
            .build()

        val locationComponentActivationOptions = LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(
            requireActivity(),
            loadedMapStyle
        )
            .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
            .build()

        mapboxMap.locationComponent.apply {
            activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions)
            isLocationComponentEnabled = true
            renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS
            cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
        }
    }

    override fun onExplanationNeeded(permissionsToExplain: MutableList<String>?) {
        // TODO some explanation can be shown here
    }

    override fun onPermissionResult(granted: Boolean) {
        if (granted) mapboxMap.getStyle { loadedStyle -> starLocationTracking(loadedStyle) }
        //else TODO some explanation can be shown here
    }

    fun onMapBoxRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) = permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.mapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        binding.mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        binding.mapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releaseMapResources()
        releasePermissionsManagerListener()
    }

    private fun releaseMapResources() {
        binding.mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun releasePermissionsManagerListener() {
        permissionsManager.listener = null
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        binding.mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        binding.mapView.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

I tested the implementation above with 2 real devices and 1 emulator.
The solution works fine with the Android 10 device. User location is found, even after closing the location services and opening it again after the map, is visible.

But location is sometimes not found, sometimes it take very long, even the location services are ready before the map is visible while trying with Android 9 and Android 7 devices.

What could be the problem here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "But location is sometimes not found, sometimes it take very long,
>   even the location services are ready before the map is visible while
>   trying with Android 9 and Android 7 devices."

This sounds as if the device tries to obtain the location from the GPS sensor, but takes long to retrieve it. With newer devices and Android 10 localization has been improved, so this could explain what you are seeing.

To understand what is going on, I would recommend to implement the [Android FusedLocationProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) and compare the behaviour to the one wrapped by Mapbox SDKs (locationComponent).

Also, please check whether the "snappy" location you get with Android 10 is actually retrieved from the GPS sensor, or if it is "just" the last known location, that was cached by Android.